# Spherical solution of the heat equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $g(x,y,z,t)$ satisfies
$$
g_t=g_{xx}+g_{yy}+g_{zz}
$$
and $g(x,y,z,t)=h(r,t)$, where $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$.

Is it correct that the equation $h_t-h_{rr}-\frac{2}{r}h_r=0$ is satisfied by $h(r,t)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the equation

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} = \nabla^2 g$$

If you let $g(x,y,z,t) = h(r,t)$ then you are changing to other coordinate system. Then you'll have that, time is the same

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial t}$$

And also

$$\nabla^2 g = \nabla^2 h \stackrel{\text{spherical}}{=} \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial h}{\partial r}\right) = \frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial h}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial ^2 h}{\partial r^2}$$

So

> $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}-\nabla^2g =0 \implies \frac{\partial h}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial ^2h}{\partial r^2} - \frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial h}{\partial r} = 0$$

Comment: Thanks. Your answer actually confirms my guess and that is all asked.